# Can i put 3 different authentication schemes in same spring security configuration?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-security

My requirement is to provide:

1. Userid password based authentication.
2. Open id based authentication
3. Url based authentication (its a custom sso impl we have)

in the same project.

I have tried to plug in Spring security into an existing project as (code stripped down for simplicity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="false">
        <remember-me user-service-ref="rememberMeUserService" key="some custom key" /> <!-- TODO: Key made for testing reasons.... -->
        <intercept-url pattern='/mainApplication/Main screen.html' access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern='/**' filters="none"/> <!-- Allow entry to login screen -->
        <openid-login authentication-failure-url="/Login.html?error=true" default-target-url="/mainApplication/Main screen.html" user-service-ref="openIdUserService"/>
        <form-login login-page="/Login.html" authentication-failure-url="/Login.html?error=true" always-use-default-target="true" default-target-url="/mainApplication/Main screen.html"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeUserService" class="mypackage.CustomUserService">
        <beans:property name="usersService" ref="usersService"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Common login shared entry-point for both Form and OpenID based logins -->    
    <beans:bean id="entryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/Login.html" />
    </beans:bean>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="MyCustomAuthenticationProvider" class="mypackage.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
        <custom-authentication-provider />
        <beans:property name="usersService" ref="usersService"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="openIdAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.providers.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationProvider">
        <custom-authentication-provider />
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="openIdUserService"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="openIdUserService" class="mypackage.OpenIDUserDetailsService">
        <beans:property name="usersService" ref="usersService"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Great, now i want to include SSO based sign on -->
    <!-- need to intercept a url of the form :   /myApp/customLogin/<key> where <key> is my token key   -->

</beans:beans>
```

as mentioned above, i need to track a url of the form : /myApp/customLogin/12345 where 1235 is the token key, we were initially using (code stripped down for simplicity)

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mySSOCapture</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myApp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What should i do here to enable spring security to help me manage this third authentication scheme ?

a corollary question is :
can i have many authentication providers in the same project ? 
if yes, then how can they be matched to different functionalities (eg one providing url based authentication, one providing anonomous auth, etc) ?

Comment: sso : Single Sign on (user is authenticated by merely having a token). The servlet-mapping written above is in my web.xml. The Open id authentication and the username password authentication are working fine.My login page contains two forms one for normal login and other for open id based login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is the solution:

```
<beans:bean id="mySsoFilter" class="somePackage.MySsoProcessingFilter">
    <custom-filter after="CAS_PROCESSING_FILTER"/> <!-- Just a reference Point-->
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value='/mainApplication/Main screen.html' />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="/Login.html?error=true"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Hope this helps someone in need...

Comment: just as i used the "after", i also used "before" to add another SSO !!   Please note that CAS has nothing to do with my system.

Answer (score 1):

Can't answer the question directly, but a 'helpful hint' from the Identity Management sector: Not all authentication systems have the same trust value - It is a serious breach of good security design to treat them equally.

I hope this helps with your design...

Comment: well, it does add a philosopihical dimension to my question :D
i dont see the point of this answer though

Comment: I was just suggesting something to look out for.  Sorry if it doesn't apply to you.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably several ways to do this. There is some functionality that does something very similar, namely [Pre-authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/preauth.html). It's a good example of a way that you can add a custom filter that authenticates the user, after which the rest of the framework should take over.

What an `AuthenticationProvider` does is examine the `Authentication` object that is loaded into the session by a previous filter. You can register as many authentication providers as you want with the authentication manager (which simply runs the `Authentication` object through all of them), but you have to manage to get some filter in there that will handle your authentication scheme and populate the `Authentication` object. If you want this filter to also interact with the user (i.e. show a login form or something) it might interfere with other filters. In that case you can use separate filter chains, but this doesn't sound like it would be necessary in your case.

Comment: I read about PreAuthentication, i think you are mistaken with my question, i wanted to allow users to login in 3 different ways:
username/password, Open Id, SSO.

Comment: I do appreciate the extra information about authentication managers, that infor has cleared a few of my basics, i am unsure about what you meant with regards to filter chains.

Comment: Sorry I figured your login scheme was too different from the rest to be able to fit it in nicely there. As for filter chains, basically there is one chain of spring security filters that all requests go through, but if necessary you can set up two or more, filtering on different URLs. That way you can use completely different filters/authentication mechanisms, but it gets a bit complicated.